# Bootstrap nav-tabs without IDs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I want to make a plugin that displays information on different tabs.

it has to work with multiple instances on one page, so i can not (and don't want to) use IDs

is it possible to use the tabs anyway? by data-attribute for example? as far as i see it, they only address divs with `id` as target

thanks

edit: i noticed it does work with classes. but again: if i have multiple instances, how can i distinguish between the "right" tab to show?

edit:
code

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab">Other</a></li>
    </ul>


    <div class="tab-content">

        <div <!-- how to reference this? --> </div>
        <div <!-- how to reference this? --> </div>

    </div>
```

if i `show()`a tab, it opens the div with the corresponding `id`, right?
but how to do it without `id`?

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean when you say "it has to work with multiple instances on one page". Does that mean multiple tabs, or multiple sets of tabs? In either case, I do not understand why IDs will not work, as each ID is always unique.

Comment: If you just want to do this with classes instead of IDs, then this should work - https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19435/.

Comment: multiple SETS of tabs that are auto-generated (that's why i can't use ids and just targeting classes will select all of them across the page)

Comment: @devman I am having the same issue and question as you had. Did you ever find an elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

The `data-target` attribute can get a css selector. (for example `data=target=".somewhere .tab1"`)

But this does not remove the need to give some sense of context. If you just say: toggle `.class1` then it will toggle all elements that have `class="class1"`. Therefore you need to make it kind of unique in some way.